# How do I keep all my elements in order on a webpage on a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, media-queries

Here  is my website:

maitxhomes.com/main.html

It looks great (I hope) on desktop browsers, but when I pull it up on my phone, the blue section's content is just in a big column that extends all the way down, and the same thing happens with my footer's content. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the `<ul>` in my HTML code, or the CSS? Is there a @media query I can add to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to design layout responsive on various devices like mobile-phones, tablets, desktops etc. you link bootstrap file to your website acordingly i.e if you want your website for desktops you use ".col-md" or "col-lg" class.

but if you want to display your website correctly on small devices like mobile phone... you should add 'col-xs' class.

for ex:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4">content 1</div>
<div calss="col-xs-9 col-sm-8">Main content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I think, this should solve the issue you are facing.

for more info:
go through the following link

[Bootstrap Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: That worked beautifully!  Thank you so much.

Can I ask, what does md lg and xs mean? Medium, large and extra-small, I guess? Are there any advantages to *not* using xs?

Comment: you are welcome. it basically the pixels being alloted on implementation of each class. xs class is best for displaying websites to those guys who use phone with rally small dislay, like the really cheap small phone provided by samsung. there is no harm in including the col-xs class. it will certainly increase your website responsive ness.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rule on `.container` that sets the `width`. Also remove the rule from `tri-section` that sets a `height`.

Remove from `line 3`:

```
.container {
  width: 960px
}
```

And `line 189`:

```
.tri-section {
  height: 130px;
}
```

By writing explicit `height` and `width` values, you are making those element **non-responsive**.

Just to add a little bit to my answers, I've addressed your specific problems, but you should really consider developing *websites* with [a mobile first](http://zurb.com/word/mobile-first) approach if you at all expect users to interact with your site from a non-desktop sized screen.

You are likely going to run into more issues taking a desktop first approach.